# jquery-ui sortable: how not to add cells on dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some table, For example:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped" id="mytable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Table heading 1</th>
        <th>Table heading 2</th>
        <th>Table heading 3</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
        <td>Table cell</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I want to make sortable table's row-headers.

```
$('#mytable thead tr').sortable({
    axis: "x",
    helper: "clone"
}).disableSelection();
```

**The Problem:**

When I start Drag-n-Drop, I have 6 `th`-s instead of 4:

```
<tr class="ui-sortable">
    <th>#</th>
    <th style="
        display: none;">Table heading 1</th>
    <th class="ui-sortable-placeholder" 
        style="
            visibility: hidden;"></th>
    <th>Table heading 2</th>
    <th>Table heading 3</th>
    <th style="
            display: table-cell; 
            width: 343px; 
            height: 37px; 
            position: absolute; 
            z-index: 1000; 
            left: 184px;" 
        class="ui-sortable-helper">Table heading 1</th>
</tr>
```

..and all the mark-up starts being very unstable and uncertain: while I drag `th` item over table, I see all rows jumping in size.

It's evident that this happens because of count `th` items (which are not equal to number of `td` items in `tr`).

How to repair this?

Comment: this library does just that : http://www.danvk.org/wp/dragtable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you start dragging it creates two new `th` elements. one is not displayed so it doesn't seem to effect anything. The second one is a placeholder for the original element while you drag it around. The width of this new element isn't set so it auto sizes to the columns largest width which appears to be whats causing it to jump around.

To counter this I changed the width of the placeholder element to the width of the element we are dragging in the start function. Hope this helps

```
start: function(event, ui){
    $(".ui-sortable-placeholder").css({width: $(ui.item).width()});
```

Below is the code and here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt9388/DDxK7/)

```
$(function () {
$('#mytable thead tr').sortable({
    axis: "x",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui){
        $(".ui-sortable-placeholder").css({width: $(ui.item).width()});    
    }
}).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: This makes life better. But still not the solution: it looks like width() executes after item is being picked-up, and width of placeholder depends on width of content of tbody's row. For example, the first row becomes very tiny. BTW, your jsfiddle link links to page without any code.

Comment: Uhh. On unstiled table it runs pretty fine. But if add link to bootstrap css, this drag-n-drop acts very unexpectedly strange.

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle of what you have so i can see what it's doing?